# Ajax-Based Website displays "Google Search" on link Click?

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I hope someone could help me ..

On my website, i call links this way:

```
onClick="show_content('profile', '1', 'Christoph');"
```

This function only changes the Hash-Tag:

```
    function show_content(hash_page, hash_id, urlname) {
        if (hash_id) {
            if (urlname) {
        document.location.hash =  "!/" + hash_page + "/" + hash_id + "/" + urlname;
            } else {
        document.location.hash =  "!/" + hash_page + "/" + hash_id;
            }
        }  else {
        document.location.hash =  "!/" + hash_page;
        }
    }
```

And this function "listens" for new Hash-Tags, and do the jQuery $ajax-Load if needed.

```
  $(function(){

  $(window).hashchange( function(){
    loadContent(location.hash);
  })

  // Trigger
  $(window).hashchange();

});
```

> Now, if i click any link on my mobile-browser, Chrome(Android) show me a such "search" bar at the bottom of the Screen (which contains "Dominic" in this Case, after the Click.. (Dominic is a Part of the Link-Name on the Website)
>
> Can someone say me why, and how to avoid this ?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I recall seeing this question a few days ago... did you delete it and repost it?

Comment: okay, after days of thinking, and posting it to Stackoverflow, i got a brainwave and it could be so easy.. 

I listen for new Hashtags, and my function changes the hashtags.. I dont know why i forget this way, but i form links like this:

<a href="#!/profil/1/Christoph">Userprofil 1</a>

And it works perfect..

Sorry @moderator's.. I don't know how to add code-blocks in a comment.

Comment: You wrap them in \` characters to format in comment. but, that code would likely have been better if added directly to your question.